# Function Expression vs Function Declaration in Javascript Decorators

Tags: javascript, decorator, function-expression, javascript-decorators

I have a problem understanding how different ways to create a function are affecting decorators. I am trying to create a decorator that will allow me to count how may times function was called:

```js
function counter(func) {

    wrapper = function(...args) {
        wrapper.counter++;
        let arguments = [].slice.call(args, 0)
        let result = func.apply(null, arguments);
        return result;
    }

    wrapper.counter = 0;
    return wrapper;
}

function sum(x, y, z) {
    return x + y + z
}

function mul(a, b, c) {
    return a * b * c
}

a = counter(sum);
b = counter(mul);

console.log(`sum of 3, 6 and 8 is ${a(3, 6, 8)}`);
console.log(`mul of 1, 2 and 3 is ${b(1, 2, 3)}`);
console.log(`sum of 2, 2 and 2 is ${a(2, 2, 2)}`);
console.log(`mul of 5, 6 and 2 is ${b(5, 6, 2)}`);

console.log(`a.counter is ${a.counter}`);
console.log(`b.counter is ${b.counter}`);
```

This code results in following output:

```
sum of 3, 6 and 8 is 17
mul of 1, 2 and 3 is 6
sum of 2, 2 and 2 is 6
mul of 5, 6 and 2 is 60
a.counter is 0
b.counter is 4
```

As you can see, `a` and `b` are sharing reference the same counter, one that belongs to b, which shouldn't be happening.

However, if I change function expression `wrapper = function(...args)` to function declaration `function wrapper(...args)`, like this:

```js
function counter(func) {

    function wrapper(...args) {
        wrapper.counter++;
        let arguments = [].slice.call(args, 0)
        let result = func.apply(null, arguments);
        return result;
    }

    wrapper.counter = 0;
    return wrapper;
}

function sum(x, y, z) {
    return x + y + z
}

function mul(a, b, c) {
    return a * b * c
}

a = counter(sum);
b = counter(mul);

console.log(`sum of 3, 6 and 8 is ${a(3, 6, 8)}`);
console.log(`mul of 1, 2 and 3 is ${b(1, 2, 3)}`);
console.log(`sum of 2, 2 and 2 is ${a(2, 2, 2)}`);
console.log(`mul of 5, 6 and 2 is ${b(5, 6, 2)}`);

console.log(`a.counter is ${a.counter}`);
console.log(`b.counter is ${b.counter}`);
```

Then `a` and `b` are having correct counters and everything works fine:

```
sum of 3, 6 and 8 is 17
mul of 1, 2 and 3 is 6
sum of 2, 2 and 2 is 6
mul of 5, 6 and 2 is 60
a.counter is 2
b.counter is 2
```

What causes changes in behavior like that?

I tried to find solution to this problem myself, but didn't found anything of help. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sure they're referring to the same function, you haven't declared `wrapper`, it's a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here isn't to do with function expressions vs function declarations, it's to do with the fact that you're creating `wrapper` without `var`, `let` or `const` keywords. When you create a variable without one of these, they become a global variable, so it's not scoped to `counter` function. That means that when you call `counter()` the first time, it creates your wrapper function and stores a reference to that in `a`, it also creates a global  `wrapper` variable to hold the function that was just created. Calling `counter()` again then overwrites that global variable to store the new function you just created, but `a` still holds a reference to the original one. Each time you perform `wrapper.counter++;` you're now updating the global `wrapper` function' `.counter` property, which is `b`s function (not `a`'s). This results inn `a.counnter` being `0` but `b.counter` being 4.

When you do `function wrapper(...args) {}` on the other hand, `wrapper` is naturally scoped to the function/scope it's declared in, and doesn't become a global variable like in your first example. To fix your first snippet, you can declare `wrapper` with `const` to make it scoped to `counter` and to avoid creating a global variable that's accessible outside of `counter`.

```js
function counter(func) {

  const wrapper = function(...args) {
    wrapper.counter++;
    let arguments = [].slice.call(args, 0)
    let result = func.apply(null, arguments);
    return result;
  }

  wrapper.counter = 0;
  return wrapper;
}

function sum(x, y, z) {
  return x + y + z
}

function mul(a, b, c) {
  return a * b * c
}

a = counter(sum);
b = counter(mul);

console.log(`sum of 3, 6 and 8 is ${a(3, 6, 8)}`);
console.log(`mul of 1, 2 and 3 is ${b(1, 2, 3)}`);
console.log(`sum of 2, 2 and 2 is ${a(2, 2, 2)}`);
console.log(`mul of 5, 6 and 2 is ${b(5, 6, 2)}`);

console.log(`a.counter is ${a.counter}`);
console.log(`b.counter is ${b.counter}`);
```

Using `"use strict"` would've helped you catch this bug also, as in strict mode, you can't assign to an undeclared variable.

```js
"use strict";
function counter(func) {
  wrapper = function(...args) {} // "Uncaught ReferenceError: wrapper is not defined"
}

const a = counter((a, b) => a + b);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you provided, we don't see the declaration keyword before the wrapper, which means that it may have been reallocated